# How to transform green screen footage to a 3d object

Tags: blender, video-processing

I am a software developer working on an Augmented/Virtual Reality. I have no experience video processing and 3d modeling. On my project, I need to use 3d animated models that are created from green screen footage.

I use A-Frame for development. For what kind of formats it supports you can look at its docs: https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/models.html

I would like to know first of all if it's possible to accomplish and if it is, can I do it myself without much experience?

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is called [photogrammetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photogrammetry), which is not really a first project topic.

See if [AliceVision](https://github.com/alicevision/AliceVision) can help.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like I will have to go for a different route.